# How do I make the Mail app on iPhone save my sent messages to the Gmail's sent folder?

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, gmail

My iPhone has iOS 16.1. In the standard Mail app I use my Gmail account as my primary / only mail account. When I send email from this account it doesn't get stored in Gmail's Sent folder, but it does when sending from the Gmail web interface.

How do I fix this so that the Mail app will store sent mail in the Sent folder? As best I can tell no copy is stored anywhere when I send from my iPhone.

Update: Sounds like the answer is Mailbox Behaviors > Sent Mailbox but on my phone this option doesn't exist. See the image. Anyone know what option in the phone or Gmail web site addresses this?

[image: screenshot of Mail Settings]

Here are my SMTP settings:

[image: SMTP Settings]

Comment: What is the outgoing mail server set to (SMTP)?

Comment: @hawk Good question. I just added a screenshot with the SMTP settings.

Comment: Make sure the host name is set to the correct value, which [seems to be](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=638074644514439993-1320249043&hl=en&rd=1#zippy=%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client) `smtp.gmail.com` and then your sent e-mails [should automatically go to your Sent folder](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78892?hl=en#zippy=%2Canother-email-client).

Comment: It won't let me change the hardwired SMTP server for google, as seen in the screen shot in my post. It will let me add an additional one, but I can't make that one take effect since I can't delete the hardwired one.

Comment: Ok, it seems the information provided by Google at the first link is wrong because I'm unable to authenticate via either IMAP or SMTP using their settings. Try deleting and recreating the account, and if that doesn't solve your issue, then the info at the second link is likely wrong too. At that point who knows if it's possible if even Google doesn't seem to know, so you might want to take it up with Google customer support. gl

Comment: Thanks @hawk. I did delete and recreate the account on my iPhone. No change.

Comment: This clearly is meant to work since the answer from @Marc Wilson shows a screen shot of the iPhone configuring Sent Mailbox to Sent. Well, actually, that may not be on gmail, though. Hm. If you want to put some of this in an answer I'll give it the bounty since you've been quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Advanced settings for the particular Mail account.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the right answer but my phone doesn't have that option. See picture I added in the question. Any ideas?